# MySQL Update in Multiple Tables... trigger? cascade?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

I have three tables that are associated. A category contains options that user enter in values for, simplified in the following...

```
group
-----
id
name
active

option
------
id
group_id
name
active

user_option
-----------
id
opton_id
value
active
```

My question is what is the best way to handle situations where a group is deactivated. What I've done in the past is looked up option id's where the group_id = the group id that is being deactivated. Then I take the list of returned id's and deactivate the user_option like...

```
set active=0 where option_id in (list of ids)
```

Then I update option, then I update group.

I'm interested if there is a way to do this kind of thing with a trigger or cascade. I've never used either in MySQL and thought I'd see what the best approach to this problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the foreign key on the `USER_OPTION.active` column should be all that's necessary to implement your desired functionality, [per the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).  Assuming a foreign key constraint is already in place, use:

```
ALTER TABLE 
MODIFY active FOREIGN KEY fk_name (active) REFERENCES OPTION(active) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: If it's MyISAM is see FKeys are not supported. Would there be a trigger option to lookup/update, or would this basically be the same as running it the "old" way? Thanks.

Comment: @Don: Not sure where I read it, but I assumed this regarded InnoDB tables because yes, you'd have to use triggers for the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks. The tables are currently ISAM but I'm evaluating the select/insert load to see if it makes sense to convert them for the added flexibility.